# How to add Some Comment in all Class Files in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have a comment to add in all class files. There are about 200 class files in my Project. Is there any way to add some comment in all existing class files in android studio.

Comment: What comment were you going to add?  Copyright notice?

Comment: Yes, I need to add copyright notice